# VTK Interpolating values when colouring vtkPolyData with vtkImageData

Tags: vtk

I am trying to label `vtkPolyData` points with a scalar taken from my 3d volume `vtkImageData` of scalars. I have already done this, by using the `GetPoint()` function on the `vtkPolyData` point, calculating the id of the nearest point in the `vtkImageData` object, then getting the value from its scalar array. However, I would like to be able to do this by interpolating the scalar value, because currently the output is quite blocky / noisy as my 3d `vtkImageData` is formed from putting 2d slices on top of one another. I am struggling to find a way I can either interpolate the `vtkImageData` values, or get an interpolated value for my `vtkPolyData`. I have seen mentions of the `InterpolatePoint()` function and the `vtkProbeFilter`, but I am not sure about either of those as I couldn't get them to work and there isn't a lot of example code to go off.

Comment: It seems like a job for the vtkProbeFilter. Have you tried this

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried out the `vtkProbeFilter` and it seems to do the job.

```
import vtk

namedColors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

# Mesh coordinates are within the 3D image. It could be an iso surface
filename = 'mesh.vtp'
reader0 = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader0.SetFileName(filename)
reader0.Update()

# 3D image data
fileName = 'image.mhd'
reader1 = vtk.vtkMetaImageReader()
reader1.SetFileName(fileName)
reader1.Update()

rng = reader1.GetOutput().GetScalarRange()
# You can narrow this down to the range around your value used for extracting
# the iso surface
fMin = rng[0]
fMax = rng[1]
    
probe = vtk.vtkProbeFilter()
probe.SetInputConnection(reader0.GetOutputPort())
probe.SetSourceData(reader1.GetOutput())
probe.Update()

normals = vtk.vtkPolyDataNormals()
normals.SetInputConnection(probe.GetOutputPort())

lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
lut.SetTableRange(fMin, fMax)
# We want same saturation for all values in the LUT
lut.SetSaturationRange(1.0, 1.0)
lut.Build()

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
mapper.SetLookupTable(lut)
mapper.SetInputConnection(normals.GetOutputPort())
mapper.SetScalarRange(fMin, fMax)

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)

renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.SetSize(600, 600)
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

renderWindow.Render()
interactor.Start()
```

Here the code is used for coloring the surface of the hepatic veins in the Liver using values extracted from a CT image.

[image]